# Mimic "less -r" when displaying .txt file in HTML

Tags: html, ansi-escape

I have a .txt file that contains escape characters. You can't see them when you cat or more or "less -r" the file, but if you vi the file you see the following:

```
session_cache ^[[27G: 375755
```

Normal output from "cat" is:

```
session_cache : 375755
```

The ^[[27G I believe is a ANSI terminal code for tab maybe? I would like to be able to display this text file in a standard web page without having to see those escape characters.

Is this possible without having to convert the .txt file to HTML and manually remove all the different escape sequences (ie make HTML behave like cat does)?

Dan

Comment: close: not a "tab" but cursor movement to a specific column. html doesn't do that (or **any** cursor movement), but you could preprocess the file with a script to convert special cases of this escape sequence.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I had started doing that but then 1) there are so many combinations it’s difficult to get them all and 2) the resulting output looks pretty bad unless I do all my own formatting which is a lot of work.

Comment: If I had to do this (for myself), I'd adapt something which works.  Offhand, the closest would be [vile-manfilt](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/vile-snapshots/blob/master/filters/manfilt.c) (but that only handles movement within the current line).